# Which Reports can deploy in Azure Standard Website Plan?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, reporting, azure-app-service-plans

I want to know, is there any reporting tool available which supports in Azure App/Web service?

As per my reading, for SSRS its compulsory required Virtual Machine. Crystal Reports also cannot be working with Azure App/Web Service?

I don't want to take other service like Power BI or Virtual Machine to run report. So please guide me is there any solution for the same?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Do let us know what kind of reporting information or details you are intending to capture from the Reporting tool.

If I understand your questions correctly, checkout the information highlighted in the documentation (https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox):

Microsoft SQL Reporting Framework manually generating PDFs
This usage pattern does not work for Free/Shared plans due to the sandbox. However, a small set of APIs are opened for use in Basic+ plans; these APIs are designed to enable SQL Reporting framework creation of PDFs. So, these libraries should be usable for PDF generation in Basic+.

PDF generation from HTML
There are multiple libraries used to convert HTML to PDF. Many Windows/.NET specific versions leverage IE APIs and therefore leverage User32/GDI32 extensively. These APIs are largely blocked in the sandbox (regardless of plan) and therefore these frameworks do not work in the sandbox.

The following PDF generators are supported:

•   SQL Reporting framework: requires the site to run in Basic or higher

•   EVOPDF: See http://www.evopdf.com/azure-html-to-pdf-converter.aspx for vendor solution

•   Telerik reporting: requires the site to run in Basic or higher.

•   Rotativa / wkhtmltopdf: requires the site to run in Basic or higher.

•   NReco PdfGenerator (wkhtmltopdf): requires subscription plan Basic or higher

Comment: I am looking for Reporting tool like SSRS, Crystal Reports where i can make grouping, custom functions, Sorting, exporting to them many format like xls or pdf, data show/hide based on conditions, etc. Its totally OK if it support in Basic or higher. Given solution here as of me, it convert html to just pdf. In such case i programmatically need to generate HTML which i don't want. I think Telerik Reporting is same like SSRS. Right?